# Set ng-options value based on string AJAX value

Tags: angularjs, select, angular-ngmodel, ng-options

I have two select menus that are populated via AJAX JSON data fetched after page load. They are linked by their own model and look like so;

```
<select name="category" 
        id="category" 
        ng-model="category" 
        ng-options="category as category.name for category in categories track by category.name">
    <option value=''>Select category</option>
</select>

<select name="product" 
        id="product" 
        ng-disabled="!category" 
        ng-model="product" 
        ng-options="product for product in category.products">
    <option value=''>Select product</option>
</select>
```

After the form is submitted to the API, it returns an `origin`object consisting of both the `category` and `product` strings if they are used.

I thought I should then be able to set the `$scope.category` and/or `$scope.product` to the returned `origin` data to pre-select the item in the select menu/s;

```
.success(function(data)) { 
...
$scope.category = data.origin.category
...   
}
```

But this does not work...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-init` to select initial value

```
<select ng-init="initDefaultCategory(categories)" name="category" id="category" ng-model="category" ng-options="category as category.name for category in categories track by category.name">
    <option value=''>Select category</option>
  </select>

  <select ng-init="initDefaultProduct(category.products)" name="product" id="product" ng-disabled="!category" ng-model="product" ng-options="product for product in category.products">
    <option value=''>Select product</option>
  </select>
```

Working **[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/dRlfR6N9PZSpqAisrElM?p=preview)**

**EDITS**

If you want to select default value, you can do something like this

**Controller**

```
$scope.initDefaultCategory = function(categories, value) {
    if (categories.length > 0)
      $scope.category = categories.filter(e => e.name == value)[0];
  }
```

And you can pass value in `ng-init`

```
  <select ng-init="initDefaultCategory(categories,'All')" name="category" id="category" ng-model="category" ng-options="category as category.name for category in categories track by category.name">
    <option value=''>Select category</option>
  </select>
```

[Edited Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/hNyddt1rFTm7gToR19kK?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks Nagaveer. Maybe i was not clear enough - the categories are populated by the same AJAX call, so an init to check against the categories will fail because they do not exist yet. Also, i am not looking to set a Default, but match to a specific item based on a string value

Comment: I think we are getting closer but there are a couple of issues. Firstly, the ng-init is not going to work because the data set that builds the categories is also required after pagte load via AJAX. So i get a "Cannot read property 'length' of null" error. This makes sense as the categories is not populated at init. Also, my IDE does not like the "e => e.name " operators for some reason?! Thanks again

Comment: I think the behaviour is more suited to the controller than the view. But i am unsure why setting the $scope.category (or $scope.product) is not resulting in the correct (or any) value in the select menu

Comment: @Alex Otherwise You can initialize the default value on the success of AJAX call.

Answer (score 1):

```
.success(function(data)) { 
   $scope.category = $scope.categories.filter(function(val,key){
       return data.origin.category['yourKey']==val['yourKey']
   })[0]
}
```